# C: Code style for returning errors?

Tags: c, error-handling, styles, return-value

All my functions look like this:

```
short Function()
{
   short ret = 0;

   ret = FunctionA();   
   if(ret != 0) return ret;

   ret = FunctionB();
   if(ret != 0) return ret;

   ret = FunctionC();
   if(ret != 0) return ret;

   return 0;
}
```

Is there a nicer way to write this? Without having to repeat

```
if(ret != 0) return ret;
```

all the time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If using a short-circuited `||` like suggested in the other answer is not an option, you could define a macro for that:

```
#define TRY(var, x) if ((var = (x))) return var
```

Then in your code:

```
short Function()
{
  short ret;

  TRY(ret, FunctionA());
  TRY(ret, FunctionB());
  TRY(ret, FunctionC());

  return 0;
}
```

**NOTE**: You should be very careful when deciding to use macros, but in this case I think it *can* be a clean way to solve the problem. 
It must be mentioned, though, that these statements conceil the fact that the function could return early at every one of them. If you have open resource handles (file descriptors, pointers to `malloc`ed data, ...), they will leak. You and everyone working with the code should be aware of this and use appropriate error handling and cleanup routines for more complex cases than this one.

Comment: very cool use of a macro, never knew you could use a if statment in a macro.

Comment: `do { ret = (x); if (ret != 0) return ret; } while (0)` is a better alternative!

Comment: And then hand it to a n00b for maintenance :(

Comment: @Marlon: I know that construct, but I'm not sure how it's applicable in that case. You'd have the same problem, only that you'd have to `break` instead of `return` if an error occurse.

Comment: @The Elite Noob: It's one of the very rare cases where I actually use macros, because it makes my life so much easier (or maybe because I just don't know how to do it properly :)

Comment: @Marlon: Why not use a simple block there? Every half-way decent compiler should support it by now.

Comment: This is the only answer that really provides a solution the question, IMO. The question was *"Is there a nicer way to write this? Without having to repeat ..."*. The only real answer is to use a macro, although you may question whether a macro is *nicer*, it definitely solves the *without having to repeat* part. This macro could be rewritten to be *nicer*, though.

Comment: @Marlon: I'm open for suggestions (apart from the do-while stuff, that doesn't really change anything :)

Comment: @NiklasB. It does; it forces you to put a `;` at the end of the statement. Yours would work just the same if you dropped the `{`, `}`, and `;` from your macro. I would probably rewrite it like this `#define TRY(result, x) if (result = (x)) return result`

Comment: @Marlon: Okay, that seems sensible.

Answer (score 5):

```
short Function()
{
   short ret = 0;

   if(
       (ret = FunctionA()) != 0 ||
       (ret = FunctionB()) != 0 ||
       (ret = FunctionC()) != 0
     )
   {
      return ret;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 I'm voting for this one -- hiding a return statement and a variable name (the other answer) in a macro is code i'd not want to deal with.

Comment: @Justin: Hm, if it's used properly and consistently in a code base it can be very clean and convenient, IMHO. It's not like keeping this one thing (use that macro to propagate errors in sub-functions) in your head is extraordinarly demanding.

Comment: @MrLister: Yep, sorry - deleted!

Comment: @NiklasB. then you have had far better experiences than I have had when dealing with others' macros :)

Comment: @Justin: I doubt that really much. Maybe you have a point. Still, I think error handling is indeed a place where decent use of macros can save of lot of repetitive code (with the premise that everyone in the team follows consistent conventions here).

Comment: @Niklas B. Surely, some people will agree with your solution. Your program does reduce character count -- that was not my objection. My point was that I'd prefer to work with Tim's program because it shortens the program (answers the question), without obfuscating anything (as a macro does). This obfuscation affects developers and tools. Among other things, Tim's program reads clearly, holds no surprises for the developer, scales better over more complex function bodies, and I'd be able to (effectively) use a debugger with it.

Comment: @Justin: Okay, thank you for this enlightening explanation :) I will leave my answer, however, I think it could still be helpful to one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going the other way, and showing you how I actually do this in the programs I write:

```
short Function() {
    short ret = 0;

    ret = FunctionA();
    if(ret != 0) {
        SomeUsefulMessageOrAssertionHere();
        return ret;
    }
    ...
```

It actually *reduces* upstream error handling code because well written diagnostics are best handled at the callsite. Of course, it does not alter the action that must be taken in the event of an error.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to rewrite this, but I can't think of anything more straightforward and easier on the eyes than yours.
Here's another variant, especially designed to minimise the number of `if ... return` statements.

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i<3; +i) {
   switch (i) {
      case 0: ret = FunctionA(); break;
      case 1: ret = FunctionB(); break;
      case 2: ret = FunctionC(); break;
   }
   if (ret != 0) return ret;
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Well, for one thing, this would allow you to do a bit of optimising, in that you can count how many times the loop runs before finding the right answer. Suppose FunctionB is more often correct than FunctionA, then you can put FunctionB first. Other than that, well, it's just another variant to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This should be equivalent if I made no mistake

```
short Function()
{
   short ret = FunctionA();   
   if(ret == 0)
   {
        ret = FunctionB();
        if(ret == 0)
        {
            ret = FunctionC();
        }

    }
   return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write:

```
short ret;
if (ret = FunctionA()) return ret;
if (ret = FunctionB()) return ret;
if (ret = FunctionC()) return ret;
```

You'll possibly surprise a few of your co-workers like that, though!

An alternative, using short-circuiting, inspired by @Tim's post:

```
short ret;
return (ret = FunctionA()) || (ret = FunctionB()) || (ret = FunctionC()) ? ret : 0;
```

In C++ you can say:

```
if (short ret = FunctionA()) return ret;
```

Comment: The return with the || operator won't work, because it returns 1 or 0, not ret. You could write `return (ret = FunctionA()) || (ret = FunctionB()) || (ret = FunctionC()) ? ret :0;` though.

Comment: @MrLister: Indeed, thanks. I want to emphasize that you return `ret` in any circumstance, though.

Comment: OK, that might be the right thing to do. It does look a bit silly though, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

```
short Function() {

    short temp;

    return (temp = FunctionA()) ? temp : (temp = FunctionB()) ? temp : FunctionC();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always liked function pointers, myself.

```
int main()
{
    typedef ret-type (*Fptr)( ... args-types ... );

    const int N_FUNC = 3;
    Fptr functions[] = { FunctionA, FunctionB, FunctionC };

    short ret = 0;
    for( int i=0; ! ret && i < N_FUNCS; i++ )
        ret = functions[i];

    return ret;
}
```